# Is there any open API to get map tiles based on some coordinates?

Tags: api, maps

Is there any open API to get map tiles based on some coordinates? I would like to be able to download them (or even one tile) using HTTP in any image format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get open street map tiles. They are 256x256 Png files. They have a good article on converting lat / long to tiles numbers in about 10 different languages. It explains CloudMade, MapQuest, and Migurski as well.  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

Comment: with example, perfect answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476117/easy-openstreetmap-tile-displaying-for-python