# matplotlib basemap for small area is pixelated (Python 3)

Tags: python, matplotlib, geolocation, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using the full resolution for the map but it is still very pixelated.  I'm assuming b/c the range is pretty small but if I zoom in on Google Earth or something it all looks very detailed.  Is there a different map I need to use?  How can I increase the resolution for this area that I have?

My ranges are lons and lats
((-70.907010999999997, -70.904235999999997), (42.418675, 42.419958999999999)), respectively.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


x = np.asarray([-70.906673, -70.90654 , -70.90654 , -70.90654 , -70.906447, -70.906447, -70.906447, -70.906878, -70.906878, -70.906878, -70.906776, -70.906541, -70.906541, -70.906792, -70.906792, -70.906792, -70.906713, -70.906713, -70.906614, -70.906614, -70.906614, -70.906093, -70.906093, -70.906051, -70.905767, -70.905767, -70.90576 , -70.90576 , -70.905658, -70.905658, -70.905658, -70.905545, -70.905545, -70.905334, -70.905334, -70.905334, -70.90532 , -70.90532 , -70.905316, -70.905333, -70.90517 , -70.905198, -70.90508 , -70.90508 , -70.90508 , -70.905132, -70.904992, -70.904992, -70.904992, -70.905006, -70.904871, -70.904826, -70.904911, -70.904911, -70.904911, -70.904857, -70.904544, -70.904443, -70.904443, -70.904446, -70.904302, -70.904293, -70.904289, -70.907011, -70.907011, -70.907011, -70.906875, -70.906875, -70.906875, -70.906777, -70.906777, -70.906777, -70.906673, -70.906673, -70.906314, -70.906314, -70.906314, -70.906228, -70.906228, -70.906228, -70.906974, -70.906974, -70.906974, -70.906776, -70.906776, -70.906655, -70.906655, -70.906655, -70.906541, -70.906382, -70.906382, -70.906382, -70.906334, -70.906334, -70.906334, -70.906234, -70.906234, -70.906234, -70.906975, -70.906975, -70.906975, -70.906876, -70.906876, -70.906876, -70.906713, -70.906577, -70.906577, -70.906577, -70.906522, -70.906522, -70.906522, -70.906383, -70.906383, -70.906383, -70.906087, -70.906087, -70.906087, -70.906093, -70.906089, -70.906089, -70.906089, -70.906088, -70.906088, -70.906088, -70.906101, -70.906101, -70.906101, -70.906094, -70.906094, -70.906094, -70.906079, -70.906079, -70.906079, -70.906101, -70.906101, -70.906101, -70.906125, -70.906125, -70.906125, -70.906101, -70.906101, -70.906101, -70.906074, -70.906074, -70.906074, -70.906094, -70.906094, -70.906094, -70.906099, -70.906099, -70.906099, -70.906089, -70.906089, -70.906089, -70.906099, -70.906099, -70.906099, -70.905995, -70.905995, -70.905995, -70.905985, -70.905985, -70.905985, -70.905959, -70.905959, -70.905959, -70.905966, -70.905966, -70.905966, -70.905981, -70.905981, -70.905981, -70.905986, -70.905986, -70.905986, -70.905995, -70.905995, -70.905995, -70.905982, -70.905982, -70.905982, -70.90597 , -70.90597 , -70.90597 , -70.905975, -70.905975, -70.905975, -70.905968, -70.905968, -70.905968, -70.905996, -70.905996, -70.905996, -70.906051, -70.906051, -70.905952, -70.905952, -70.905952, -70.905972, -70.905972, -70.905972, -70.90599 , -70.90599 , -70.90599 , -70.905843, -70.905843, -70.905843, -70.90588 , -70.90588 , -70.90588 , -70.905871, -70.905871, -70.905871, -70.905887, -70.905887, -70.905887, -70.905879, -70.905879, -70.905879, -70.905888, -70.905888, -70.905888, -70.905878, -70.905878, -70.905878, -70.905888, -70.905888, -70.905888, -70.905885, -70.905885, -70.905885, -70.905871, -70.905871, -70.905871, -70.905853, -70.905853, -70.905853, -70.905889, -70.905889, -70.905889, -70.905891, -70.905891, -70.905891, -70.905922, -70.905922, -70.905922, -70.905901, -70.905901, -70.905901, -70.905793, -70.905793, -70.905793, -70.905761, -70.905761, -70.905761, -70.905782, -70.905782, -70.905782, -70.905765, -70.905765, -70.905765, -70.905743, -70.905743, -70.905743, -70.905785, -70.905785, -70.905785, -70.905785, -70.905785, -70.905785, -70.905753, -70.905753, -70.905753, -70.905767, -70.90576 , -70.905761, -70.905761, -70.905761, -70.905765, -70.905765, -70.905765, -70.905751, -70.905751, -70.905751, -70.905785, -70.905785, -70.905785, -70.905778, -70.905778, -70.905778, -70.905781, -70.905781, -70.905781, -70.90565 , -70.90565 , -70.905658, -70.905658, -70.905658, -70.905658, -70.905658, -70.905658, -70.905642, -70.905642, -70.905642, -70.905643, -70.905643, -70.905643, -70.905651, -70.905651, -70.905651, -70.905663, -70.905663, -70.905663, -70.905665, -70.905665, -70.905665, -70.905659, -70.905659, -70.905659, -70.905652, -70.905652, -70.905652, -70.905663, -70.905663, -70.905663, -70.905645, -70.905645, -70.905645, -70.905651, -70.905651, -70.905651, -70.905627, -70.905627, -70.905627, -70.905633, -70.905633, -70.905633, -70.905548, -70.905548, -70.905548, -70.905538, -70.905538, -70.905538, -70.905546, -70.905546, -70.905546, -70.905533, -70.905533, -70.905533, -70.905539, -70.905539, -70.905539, -70.905573, -70.905573, -70.905553, -70.905553, -70.905553, -70.905545, -70.905544, -70.905544, -70.905544, -70.905528, -70.905528, -70.905528, -70.905513, -70.905513, -70.905513, -70.905564, -70.905564, -70.905564, -70.905539, -70.905539, -70.905539, -70.905551, -70.905551, -70.905551, -70.905427, -70.905427, -70.90544 , -70.90544 , -70.90544 , -70.905432, -70.905432, -70.905432, -70.905443, -70.905443, -70.905443, -70.905416, -70.905416, -70.905416, -70.905405, -70.905405, -70.905405, -70.905431, -70.905431, -70.905431, -70.90543 , -70.90543 , -70.90543 , -70.905411, -70.905411, -70.905411, -70.905318, -70.905318, -70.905314, -70.905314, -70.905314, -70.90532 , -70.905323, -70.905323, -70.905323, -70.905327, -70.905327, -70.905327, -70.905325, -70.905325, -70.905325, -70.90532 , -70.90532 , -70.90532 , -70.905316, -70.905316, -70.905332, -70.905332, -70.905332, -70.905333, -70.905333, -70.905318, -70.905318, -70.905318, -70.905322, -70.905322, -70.905322, -70.905211, -70.905211, -70.905211, -70.90517 , -70.90517 , -70.905199, -70.905199, -70.905199, -70.905169, -70.905169, -70.905169, -70.905231, -70.905231, -70.905231, -70.905201, -70.905201, -70.905201, -70.905215, -70.905215, -70.905215, -70.905246, -70.905246, -70.905246, -70.905214, -70.905214, -70.905214, -70.905198, -70.905198, -70.905216, -70.905216, -70.905216, -70.905226, -70.905226, -70.905226, -70.905177, -70.905177, -70.905186, -70.905186, -70.905186, -70.905105, -70.905105, -70.905105, -70.905112, -70.905112, -70.905087, -70.905087, -70.905087, -70.905126, -70.905126, -70.905126, -70.905132, -70.905132, -70.905106, -70.905106, -70.905106, -70.905146, -70.905146, -70.905146, -70.905103, -70.905103, -70.905103, -70.905099, -70.905099, -70.905099, -70.905073, -70.905073, -70.905073, -70.905079, -70.905079, -70.905079, -70.905006, -70.905006, -70.904999, -70.904999, -70.904999, -70.904975, -70.904975, -70.904975, -70.904978, -70.904978, -70.904978, -70.904981, -70.904981, -70.904981, -70.904978, -70.904978, -70.904978, -70.904978, -70.905012, -70.905012, -70.905012, -70.905003, -70.905003, -70.905003, -70.905 , -70.905 , -70.905 , -70.904967, -70.904967, -70.904967, -70.904968, -70.904968, -70.904968, -70.904871, -70.904871, -70.904881, -70.904881, -70.904881, -70.904882, -70.904882, -70.904882, -70.904826, -70.904826, -70.904848, -70.904848, -70.904848, -70.904835, -70.904835, -70.904835, -70.90491 , -70.90491 , -70.90491 , -70.904862, -70.904862, -70.904862, -70.904878, -70.904878, -70.904878, -70.904898, -70.904898, -70.904898, -70.904857, -70.904857, -70.904869, -70.904869, -70.904869, -70.90485 , -70.90485 , -70.90485 , -70.904743, -70.904743, -70.904743, -70.904736, -70.904736, -70.904736, -70.904749, -70.904749, -70.904749, -70.904737, -70.904737, -70.904737, -70.904745, -70.904745, -70.904745, -70.904743, -70.904743, -70.904743, -70.904784, -70.904784, -70.904784, -70.904763, -70.904763, -70.904763, -70.904751, -70.904751, -70.904751, -70.904761, -70.904761, -70.904761, -70.904651, -70.904651, -70.904651, -70.904662, -70.904662, -70.904662, -70.904643, -70.904643, -70.904643, -70.904602, -70.904602, -70.904602, -70.90462 , -70.90462 , -70.90462 , -70.904634, -70.904634, -70.904634, -70.904629, -70.904629, -70.904629, -70.904633, -70.904633, -70.904633, -70.904643, -70.904643, -70.904643, -70.904652, -70.904652, -70.904652, -70.904499, -70.904499, -70.904499, -70.904544, -70.904544, -70.904557, -70.904557, -70.904557, -70.904546, -70.904546, -70.904546, -70.904538, -70.904538, -70.904538, -70.904499, -70.904499, -70.904499, -70.904539, -70.904539, -70.904539, -70.90454 , -70.90454 , -70.90454 , -70.904543, -70.904543, -70.904543, -70.904561, -70.904561, -70.904561, -70.904357, -70.904357, -70.904357, -70.904415, -70.904415, -70.904415, -70.904418, -70.904418, -70.904418, -70.904393, -70.904393, -70.904393, -70.904422, -70.904422, -70.904422, -70.904408, -70.904408, -70.904408, -70.904443, -70.904446, -70.904446, -70.904424, -70.904424, -70.904424, -70.904441, -70.904441, -70.904441, -70.904302, -70.904302, -70.904293, -70.904293, -70.904311, -70.904311, -70.904311, -70.904289, -70.904289, -70.904318, -70.904318, -70.904318, -70.904254, -70.904254, -70.904254, -70.904286, -70.904286, -70.904286, -70.904236, -70.904236, -70.904236, -70.904248, -70.904248, -70.904248, -70.904239, -70.904239, -70.904239, -70.904349, -70.904349, -70.904349])
y = np.asarray([ 42.419513, 42.419509, 42.419509, 42.419509, 42.419518, 42.419518, 42.419518, 42.419429, 42.419429, 42.419429, 42.41944 , 42.419425, 42.419425, 42.41937 , 42.41937 , 42.41937 , 42.419415, 42.419415, 42.419358, 42.419358, 42.419358, 42.419829, 42.419829, 42.41892 , 42.41934 , 42.41934 , 42.419254, 42.419254, 42.419092, 42.419092, 42.419092, 42.419315, 42.419315, 42.419875, 42.419875, 42.419875, 42.419662, 42.419662, 42.419259, 42.419009, 42.419845, 42.419191, 42.419919, 42.419919, 42.419919, 42.419527, 42.419914, 42.419914, 42.419914, 42.419823, 42.419909, 42.41965 , 42.419507, 42.419507, 42.419507, 42.418895, 42.419604, 42.419241, 42.419241, 42.41918 , 42.419822, 42.419782, 42.419501, 42.419503, 42.419503, 42.419503, 42.419498, 42.419498, 42.419498, 42.419509, 42.419509, 42.419509, 42.419513, 42.419513, 42.419508, 42.419508, 42.419508, 42.419524, 42.419524, 42.419524, 42.419433, 42.419433, 42.419433, 42.41944 , 42.41944 , 42.419428, 42.419428, 42.419428, 42.419425, 42.419415, 42.419415, 42.419415, 42.419426, 42.419426, 42.419426, 42.419445, 42.419445, 42.419445, 42.419406, 42.419406, 42.419406, 42.419363, 42.419363, 42.419363, 42.419415, 42.419403, 42.419403, 42.419403, 42.41939 , 42.41939 , 42.41939 , 42.419378, 42.419378, 42.419378, 42.419907, 42.419907, 42.419907, 42.419829, 42.419757, 42.419757, 42.419757, 42.419659, 42.419659, 42.419659, 42.419597, 42.419597, 42.419597, 42.419508, 42.419508, 42.419508, 42.419419, 42.419419, 42.419419, 42.41934 , 42.41934 , 42.41934 , 42.419256, 42.419256, 42.419256, 42.419176, 42.419176, 42.419176, 42.419087, 42.419087, 42.419087, 42.418839, 42.418839, 42.418839, 42.419015, 42.419015, 42.419015, 42.418934, 42.418934, 42.418934, 42.418754, 42.418754, 42.418754, 42.419895, 42.419895, 42.419895, 42.419848, 42.419848, 42.419848, 42.419761, 42.419761, 42.419761, 42.419678, 42.419678, 42.419678, 42.419598, 42.419598, 42.419598, 42.419515, 42.419515, 42.419515, 42.419424, 42.419424, 42.419424, 42.41936 , 42.41936 , 42.41936 , 42.419265, 42.419265, 42.419265, 42.419188, 42.419188, 42.419188, 42.419087, 42.419087, 42.419087, 42.419003, 42.419003, 42.419003, 42.41892 , 42.41892 , 42.418862, 42.418862, 42.418862, 42.418755, 42.418755, 42.418755, 42.418675, 42.418675, 42.418675, 42.419959, 42.419959, 42.419959, 42.419879, 42.419879, 42.419879, 42.419729, 42.419729, 42.419729, 42.419649, 42.419649, 42.419649, 42.419575, 42.419575, 42.419575, 42.419497, 42.419497, 42.419497, 42.419432, 42.419432, 42.419432, 42.419351, 42.419351, 42.419351, 42.419252, 42.419252, 42.419252, 42.419147, 42.419147, 42.419147, 42.419087, 42.419087, 42.419087, 42.419015, 42.419015, 42.419015, 42.418911, 42.418911, 42.418911, 42.418885, 42.418885, 42.418885, 42.418838, 42.418838, 42.418838, 42.418786, 42.418786, 42.418786, 42.419909, 42.419909, 42.419909, 42.419849, 42.419849, 42.419849, 42.419744, 42.419744, 42.419744, 42.419654, 42.419654, 42.419654, 42.419581, 42.419581, 42.419581, 42.419507, 42.419507, 42.419507, 42.419422, 42.419422, 42.419422, 42.41934 , 42.419254, 42.419174, 42.419174, 42.419174, 42.419091, 42.419091, 42.419091, 42.419016, 42.419016, 42.419016, 42.418843, 42.418843, 42.418843, 42.418915, 42.418915, 42.418915, 42.418805, 42.418805, 42.418805, 42.4199 , 42.4199 , 42.419837, 42.419837, 42.419837, 42.419745, 42.419745, 42.419745, 42.419658, 42.419658, 42.419658, 42.419589, 42.419589, 42.419589, 42.419512, 42.419512, 42.419512, 42.419419, 42.419419, 42.419419, 42.419349, 42.419349, 42.419349, 42.419268, 42.419268, 42.419268, 42.419178, 42.419178, 42.419178, 42.41901 , 42.41901 , 42.41901 , 42.418913, 42.418913, 42.418913, 42.418857, 42.418857, 42.418857, 42.418808, 42.418808, 42.418808, 42.418768, 42.418768, 42.418768, 42.419938, 42.419938, 42.419938, 42.419843, 42.419843, 42.419843, 42.419751, 42.419751, 42.419751, 42.419661, 42.419661, 42.419661, 42.419593, 42.419593, 42.419593, 42.419504, 42.419504, 42.419417, 42.419417, 42.419417, 42.419315, 42.419242, 42.419242, 42.419242, 42.419169, 42.419169, 42.419169, 42.419103, 42.419103, 42.419103, 42.418998, 42.418998, 42.418998, 42.419593, 42.419593, 42.419593, 42.41877 , 42.41877 , 42.41877 , 42.419932, 42.419932, 42.419816, 42.419816, 42.419816, 42.419745, 42.419745, 42.419745, 42.419666, 42.419666, 42.419666, 42.419584, 42.419584, 42.419584, 42.419531, 42.419531, 42.419531, 42.41936 , 42.41936 , 42.41936 , 42.419188, 42.419188, 42.419188, 42.419111, 42.419111, 42.419111, 42.419933, 42.419933, 42.41978 , 42.41978 , 42.41978 , 42.419662, 42.419592, 42.419592, 42.419592, 42.419525, 42.419525, 42.419525, 42.419432, 42.419432, 42.419432, 42.419358, 42.419358, 42.419358, 42.419259, 42.419259, 42.419123, 42.419123, 42.419123, 42.419009, 42.419009, 42.418913, 42.418913, 42.418913, 42.418832, 42.418832, 42.418832, 42.419921, 42.419921, 42.419921, 42.419845, 42.419845, 42.419764, 42.419764, 42.419764, 42.419683, 42.419683, 42.419683, 42.419575, 42.419575, 42.419575, 42.419532, 42.419532, 42.419532, 42.419475, 42.419475, 42.419475, 42.419341, 42.419341, 42.419341, 42.419283, 42.419283, 42.419283, 42.419191, 42.419191, 42.419092, 42.419092, 42.419092, 42.419027, 42.419027, 42.419027, 42.418914, 42.418914, 42.418854, 42.418854, 42.418854, 42.419852, 42.419852, 42.419852, 42.419776, 42.419776, 42.41966 , 42.41966 , 42.41966 , 42.419578, 42.419578, 42.419578, 42.419527, 42.419527, 42.41947 , 42.41947 , 42.41947 , 42.419312, 42.419312, 42.419312, 42.419296, 42.419296, 42.419296, 42.419091, 42.419091, 42.419091, 42.419015, 42.419015, 42.419015, 42.418931, 42.418931, 42.418931, 42.419823, 42.419823, 42.419741, 42.419741, 42.419741, 42.419642, 42.419642, 42.419642, 42.419591, 42.419591, 42.419591, 42.419499, 42.419499, 42.419499, 42.419489, 42.419489, 42.419419, 42.419419, 42.419332, 42.419332, 42.419332, 42.419191, 42.419191, 42.419191, 42.419096, 42.419096, 42.419096, 42.419006, 42.419006, 42.419006, 42.418911, 42.418911, 42.418911, 42.419909, 42.419909, 42.419799, 42.419799, 42.419799, 42.41971 , 42.41971 , 42.41971 , 42.41965 , 42.41965 , 42.419524, 42.419524, 42.419524, 42.419447, 42.419447, 42.419447, 42.419256, 42.419256, 42.419256, 42.419187, 42.419187, 42.419187, 42.419094, 42.419094, 42.419094, 42.418984, 42.418984, 42.418984, 42.418895, 42.418895, 42.418839, 42.418839, 42.418839, 42.418826, 42.418826, 42.418826, 42.419838, 42.419838, 42.419838, 42.41976 , 42.41976 , 42.41976 , 42.419597, 42.419597, 42.419597, 42.419468, 42.419468, 42.419468, 42.419419, 42.419419, 42.419419, 42.419228, 42.419228, 42.419228, 42.419152, 42.419152, 42.419152, 42.419096, 42.419096, 42.419096, 42.419015, 42.419015, 42.419015, 42.41894 , 42.41894 , 42.41894 , 42.419839, 42.419839, 42.419839, 42.419781, 42.419781, 42.419781, 42.419586, 42.419586, 42.419586, 42.419475, 42.419475, 42.419475, 42.419443, 42.419443, 42.419443, 42.419247, 42.419247, 42.419247, 42.419175, 42.419175, 42.419175, 42.419096, 42.419096, 42.419096, 42.419017, 42.419017, 42.419017, 42.418922, 42.418922, 42.418922, 42.419805, 42.419805, 42.419805, 42.419604, 42.419604, 42.419557, 42.419557, 42.419557, 42.419475, 42.419475, 42.419475, 42.419406, 42.419406, 42.419406, 42.419239, 42.419239, 42.419239, 42.419174, 42.419174, 42.419174, 42.419094, 42.419094, 42.419094, 42.419005, 42.419005, 42.419005, 42.418896, 42.418896, 42.418896, 42.419796, 42.419796, 42.419796, 42.419758, 42.419758, 42.419758, 42.419664, 42.419664, 42.419664, 42.419573, 42.419573, 42.419573, 42.419516, 42.419516, 42.419516, 42.419432, 42.419432, 42.419432, 42.419241, 42.41918 , 42.41918 , 42.419096, 42.419096, 42.419096, 42.419002, 42.419002, 42.419002, 42.419822, 42.419822, 42.419782, 42.419782, 42.419703, 42.419703, 42.419703, 42.419501, 42.419501, 42.419415, 42.419415, 42.419415, 42.419338, 42.419338, 42.419338, 42.419249, 42.419249, 42.419249, 42.419152, 42.419152, 42.419152, 42.419056, 42.419056, 42.419056, 42.418976, 42.418976, 42.418976, 42.418828, 42.418828, 42.418828])




lons = (x.min(), x.max())
lats = (y.min(), y.max())


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
pad = 0.5
m = Basemap(projection='lcc',
            resolution="f",
            llcrnrlon=lons[0]-pad, 
            urcrnrlon=lons[1]+pad,
            llcrnrlat=lats[0]-pad,
            urcrnrlat=lats[1]+pad,
            lon_0=np.mean(lons),
            lat_0=np.mean(lats),
#             ax=ax
           )
m.bluemarble(ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: You have zoomed in beyond the intended use of the provided bluemarble image.

Comment: Maybe as a different map source use OpenStreetMap. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476117/easy-openstreetmap-tile-displaying-for-python)  would be a way to get the map into basemap.