# Basemap library using Anaconda Jupyter Notebooks - KeyError: PROJ_LIB

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to install and import the Basemap library into my Jupyter Notebook, but this returns the following error:

```
KeyError: 'PROJ_LIB'
```

After some research online, I understand I'm to install Basemap on a separate environment in Anaconda. After creating a new environment and installing Basemap (as well as all other relevant libraries), I have activated the environment. But when importing Basemap I still receive the same KeyError.

Here's what I did in my MacOS terminal:

```
conda create --name Py3.6 python=3.6 basemap
source activate Py3.6
conda upgrade proj4
env | grep -i proj
conda update --channel conda-forge proj4
```

Then in Jupyter Notebook I run the following:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

Can anyone tell me why this results in a KeyError?

Answer (score 15):

Need to set the PROJ_LIB environment variable either before starting your notebook or in python with `os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = '<path_to_anaconda>/share/proj'`

Ref. [Basemap import error in PyCharm —— KeyError: 'PROJ_LIB'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295117/basemap-import-error-in-pycharm-keyerror-proj-lib)

Comment: Thank you so much.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


import os;#--------
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = '/MYFOLDER/anaconda3/share/proj';#-------
mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

Comment: Is there really no other way than putting that line into the code?! I got this error after building a new conda environment from scratch.

Comment: OK: I edited /home/.../miniconda2/envs/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py to include the line of your answer, so that the variable is set regardless from where the plotting script is executed.

Comment: For SageMaker notebooks, I had to do this (painful): # conda install basemap
# conda install -c conda-forge proj4
# conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires
# cp /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/pkgs/proj4-5.2.0-he6710b0_1/share/proj/epsg /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/share

import os
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/share"

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

Comment: I don't see the solution anywhere, but the following will be consistent for deploying notebooks anywhere.

`os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = os.environ['CONDA_PREFIX'] + '/share/proj'`

Answer (score 12):

In Windows 10 command line: first find the directory where the **epsg** file is stored:

```
where /r "c:\Users\username" epsg.*
```

...

**c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\envname\Library\share**\epsg

...

then either in command line:

```
activate envname

SET PROJ_LIB=c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\envname\Library\share
```

(make sure there are no leading on trailing spaces in the path!) and then

```
jupyter notebook
```

or add this to your jupyter notebook (as suggested by john ed):

```
import os

os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\envname\Library\share'
```

Comment: This solution does work. Thanks for your contribution, @Pavlo. The key was to set the `os.environ['PROJ_LIB']` to the path  of the folder that contains the `epsg` file.

Comment: I fixed it by coding in the Anaconda Jupyter notebook: import os

os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'c:\Users\Paisa\anaconda3\Library\share', after trying MANY other proposals

Answer (score 7):

The problem occurs as the file location of "epsg" and PROJ_LIB has been changed for recent versions of python, but somehow they forgot to update the **init**.py for Basemap. If you have installed python using anaconda, this is a possible location for your espg file:

`C:\Users\(xxxx)\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\proj4-5.1.0-hfa6e2cd_1\Library\share`

So you have to add this path at the start of your code in spyder or whatever field you are using.

```py
import os

os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'C:\Users\(xxxx)\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\proj4-5.1.0-hfa6e2cd_1\Library\share'

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

Answer (score 1):

If you **can not locate epsg file** at all, you can download it here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matplotlib/basemap/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/epsg

And copy this file to your PATH, e.g. to:

os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = 'C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\pkgs\basemap-1.2.0-py37h4e5d7af_0\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\data\'

This is the ONLY solution that worked for me on Windows 10 / Anaconda 3.

Answer (score -3):

Launch Jupyter Notebook from command prompt and it won't throw the same error. It somehow works for me!