# scatter plot on map in django app raises basemap error

Tags: python, django, matplotlib-basemap

I created a scatter plot on indian map in jupyter notebook but when i am trying to run the same code in my djnago app. It raises

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'
```

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

# make up some data for scatter plot
lats = np.random.randint(6, 37, size=50)
lons = np.random.randint(68, 97, size=50)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(8, 6.5)

m = Basemap(projection='cyl', \
            llcrnrlat=6., urcrnrlat=37., \
            llcrnrlon=68., urcrnrlon=97., \
            lat_ts=20, \
            resolution='c',epsg=3857)

m.bluemarble(scale=1)   
m.drawcoastlines(color='white', linewidth=0.2) 
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#D3D3D3')


x, y = m(lons, lats) 
plt.scatter(x, y, 10, marker='o', color='Red') 

plt.show()
```

I am using the same conda interpreter in my django app. whats is the reason for this error ?

Comment: Then you are using a different environment.

Comment: How can I change the environment of pycharm to that of jupyter ?

Comment: Well I don't know. I don't use neither pycharm nor conda and you are the one installing the interpreters and creating and choosing the environments. But the error message says that `basemap` is not properly installed for that particular combination of interpreter and environment, that is all I know.

Comment: I have run your code in my Jupyter (without Django) and I've got the same error:  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'`. Now I'm not shure wether something has changes with basemap or wether I have to install some additional packages for basemap.

Comment: @pyano I was unable to find a proper solution, If you do please share.

Comment: You have to install basemap. Try that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356192/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mpl-toolkits-basemap (it did not work for me - yet). And have a look here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374441/python-basemap-module-impossible-to-import

Answer (score 0):

I use Anaconda under Win10. With a different OS or installation the solution may be different for you, but I can try to sketch the path.

1. You have to install Basemap. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356192/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mpl-toolkits-basemap) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374441/python-basemap-module-impossible-to-import). For me `conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires` did work.
2. When importing `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap` I got an error: `KeyError: PROJ_LIB`. Following the experiences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52911232/basemap-library-using-anaconda-jupyter-notebooks-keyerror-proj-lib) you must find a directory *share* with *epsg* inside. It is expected to be in the *conda* or the *anaconda* directory.
3. I did a search in my *Anaconda3*-dirctory and have found this path: `"C:\Anaconda3\Library\share"`
4. Then the following code did work for me (*and your code gives a nice picture too* :-) :

   ```
   import os
   proj_lib = "C:\Anaconda3\Library\share"
   os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = proj_lib

   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

   plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
   m = Basemap(projection='ortho', resolution=None, lat_0=50, lon_0=-100)
   m.bluemarble(scale=0.5);
   ```

Comment: I was able to run the code in  Jupyter Notebook, but couldn't do the same in Django